# Blur border of a canvas shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How would I make a canvas shape go out of focus?

I've seen it done with webGl and I was hoping there was a way to do it with canvas and JS?

I want to be able to animate the amount of blur so I can't use an image.

Comment: this article might help: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want a Javascript library.  Here's a good one for that purpose that allows you to pick an X,Y and width/height on the canvas to blur:

http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlur.js

And here's the demo:

http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html